# How to kill background job in resque like the gem sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, sidekiq

I use rescue gem for managing my background jobs,

I want get the handle id after creating an new background job,

Then I can kill the background job anytime with the handle id.

But I couldn’t get it with resque, it seems there is no way to delete any queued job or running job,

I know that sidekiq has the way to deleted queued jobs

[how to delete a job in sidekiq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101253/how-to-delete-a-job-in-sidekiq)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ResqueStatus](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) gem to keep track of the job and delete it using id, if needed.

Following is an example given in the gem [Docs](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/blob/master/README.rdoc#usage):

**Your job class:**

```
class SleepJob
  include Resque::Plugins::Status

  def perform
    # your code
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

**Enqueue the job and get job id:**

```
job_id = SleepJob.create(args)
```

**Kill the job using job id:**

```
Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.kill(job_id)
```

Read More on [**Github**](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status)