# Sidekiq find jobs related to specific instance in a specefic queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've just changed my job scheduler from `delayed_jobs` to `sidekiq` on my Rails app.
In `Delayed_jobs`, once we deleted an instance of the model `Order`, we then deleted the related jobs like this:

```
jobs = Delayed::Job.where("handler LIKE '%/Order/?%'", id).where(queue: queue)
jobs&.destroy_all
```

Now, as `Sidekiq` doesn't work on our DB, I've used the documentation from the Sidekiq API and been trying to do it this way:

```
rs = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new
ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
ds = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new
[rs, ss, ds].each do |set|
   set.scan("Order/#{id}").map(&:delete) if set.any?
end
```

The problem with this is that I'm not searching in the specific queue, so any job related with the instance Order/id will be deleted and I want to delete just the ones in an specific queue.

Comment: You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101810/2622934).  Then you can apply that same idea to things like `Sidekiq::DeadSet`.